# Convert List(of T) into comma-separated string of Id's

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0

I have a number of classes that all implement the same interface. e.g.

```
Public Class IncidentAsset
    Implements IModelWithIdentity

    Private _assetId As Int16
    Private _otherAsset As String

    Private _asset As Asset

    Public Property AssetId() As Int16
        Get
            Return _assetId
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Int16)
            _assetId = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property OtherAsset() As String
        Get
            Return _otherAsset
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _otherAsset = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Asset() As Asset
        Get
            Return _asset
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Asset)
            _asset = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Function GetId() As String Implements IModelWithIdentity.GetId
        Return _assetId.ToString()
    End Function
End Class
```

I have another object with a list of these objects.

```
    Public Property IncidentAssetsDamaged() As List(Of IncidentAsset)
        Get
            Return _incidentAssetsDamaged
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of IncidentAsset))
            _incidentAssetsDamaged = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

I need to write a method that will return a comma-separated string of Id's using the GetId() method of the interface.

This is what I have so far:

```
    Public Shared Function ToCommaSeparatedStringOfIds(Of T)(ByVal collection As List(Of T)) As String

        Dim array As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

        For Each obj As IModelWithIdentity In collection
            array.Add(obj.GetId())
        Next

        Return String.Join(",", array.ToArray)
    End Function
```

Is there a better way of doing this in VB.NET using .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 2):

There are few options I can see. If you specify the capacity of the list, the performance will be increased. Because List.Add() takes some extra steps to resize the collection.

Why not use a stringbuilder, and append comma at the end of each id's.

Dim builder As New StringBuilder()

```
 For Each obj As IModelWithIdentity In collection
            builder.Append(obj.GetId()).append(",")
 Next
Dim res = builder.ToString()
```

But this may add an extra comma at the end.

You can sort this out by using an indexer, and conventional for loop.

```
Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
     For i = 0 To collection.Count - 2
          builder.Append(collection(i).GetId()).append(",")
     Next
     builder.Append(collection(collection.Count -1))

    Dim res = builder.ToString()
```

This is logically right. Please benchmark this and do let know the results.